# 'log10' identifier not found error on compiling

Tags: c++

I am trying to complile some trie code. Most of the part is fine except that there is a line which mentions
log10(probab)/log10(2.0)

I am getting error on this line
error : 'log10' identifier not found
error : 'log10' identifier not found

I tried to include the header file `#include <cmath>` in file, 
but on compiling I start getting huge number of errors. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xRYg.png

Here's the code [pastebin.com/XLXggW4R](http://pastebin.com/XLXggW4R) 
Can't say what specifically goes wrong on including . However, I have mentioned with a comment where it gives an error –

Comment: I see linker errors in your screenshot. No compiler error though. Post some code.

Comment: @dirkgently: Here's the code http://pastebin.com/XLXggW4R Can't say what specifically goes wrong on including <cmath>. However, I have mentioned with a comment where it gives an error

Comment: you probably include these function definitions twice or have a copy somewhere...

Comment: It seems like you may be `#including` the file you posted on pastebin.com in other .cpp files by mistake (like maybe `dllmain.cpp`).

Comment: The title of this question does not correspond to the actual problem and your errors are not in the code to which you have linked. See here: http://ideone.com/vpBVv. It would help us to help you if you provided a  [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) and not just linked to a screenshot and a whole lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: `log10(probab)/log10(2.0)` actually calculates log(propab) to base 2. It would be more 'natural' to use `log(probab)/log(2.0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are missing the `std` namespace reference on your code. You have two choices:

1. Try using `log10()` function as: `std::log10()`.
2. Add an `using` statement right next to the `#include <cmath>`.

ie:

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: You wouldn't usually encourage `using namespace std` by default. Restrict the scope to as local as is useful, best to have `using std::log10` at the top of the function.